# Django вопросы?

Tags: python, django

**Зачем использовать *python manage.py* shell** когда есть админ панель у Django

Пример

```
  class Blog(models.MODEL):
         
         name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
         description = models.TextField()
```

мы потом вернемся к API через команду **python manage.py shell**

```
  >> from books.models import Blog 
  >> Blog.objects.all()
  >> b = Blog(name='Эра',description='Новости про него')
```

Пример с  *shell*

Альтернатива к этому

Вот я создал суперпользователя через команду *py manage.py createsuperuser*

Регистрируем в *admin.py*

```
    admin.site.register
```

И мы направляем к **Django Admin Site**

Вон там мы можем добавить в класс *Blog* имя и описания.

Вопрос в том зачем добавлять через базу через Shell когда есть Django admin Вон тут вопросик

Спасибо за ваш ответ!

Comment: «Зачем использовать python manage.py shell» — если вам не нужно, то и незачем.

Comment: Нет просто не могу найти различие между ними. Можно добавлять в базу и с shell и через django admin. Вот вопрос

Comment: shell позволяет выполнить любой python-код, добавление в базу лишь один из вариантов написания кода. Если вам хватает возможностей django admin, то и shell вам ни к чему

Comment: через shell в основном дебажат код или можно выполнять самописные команды через manage. В качестве инструмента добавления записей в базу shell не используется

Comment: Огромное спасибо за обьяснение